# How to - Tomcat populate singleton string list from context

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, context.xml

At tomcat server, I need to populate singleton string list by reading value from **Context.xml/Server.xml/Web.xml** with jndi for spring application. I found no tags carry list param not **Environment/Resource/Parameter**.

I found a solve

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>SystemVariables</param-name>
  <param-value>ex1.com,ex2.com,ex3.com</param-value>
</context-param>
```

From where after picking the value I have to split it then populate the list.

But previously we use resin where we put jndi like following

```
<resource jndi-name="SystemVariables">
     <type>com.example.SystemVariables</type>
     <init>
        <VarDescList>ex1.com</VarDescList>
        <VarDescList>ex2.com</VarDescList>
        <VarDescList>ex3.com</VarDescList>
     </init>
</resource>
```

How do we make it work at tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no way to define a list of entries. But in context.xml you can define 'ResourceLink' and create your own factory that will parse a file and return whatever you need.

Factory code would be very simple so it may be much more worthwhile to just create a bit of code instead of spending hours on google in search of the answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of problem. I would prefer comma separated one and create factory class to split the elements. Following what I did to solve this-

```
<Resource name="SystemVariables"
       type="com.example.SystemVariables"
       factory="com.example.SystemVariablesFactory"
       VarDescList="ex1.com,ex2.com,ex3.com"/>
```